# Unable to connect to ODI using ODI sdk from remote system

Tags: java, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to connect to ODI using ODI SDK in java. Here is the code to get the ODI Instance:

```
MasterRepositoryDbInfo masterInfo = new MasterRepositoryDbInfo("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:1521:xe", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", username, password, new PoolingAttributes());
WorkRepositoryDbInfo workInfo = new WorkRepositoryDbInfo("WORKREP1", new PoolingAttributes());

final OdiInstance odiInstance = OdiInstance.createInstance(new OdiInstanceConfig(masterInfo, workInfo));
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" oracle.odi.core.config.WorkRepositoryResourceFailureException: ODI-10182: Uncategorized exception during repository access.  
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.odi.core.repository.Repository.getWorkRepository(Repository.java:195)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.createWorkRepository(OdiInstance.java:531)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.<init>(OdiInstance.java:678)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.createInstance(OdiInstance.java:609)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.createInstance(OdiInstance.java:548)
    at com.fe.FT2FT.main(FT2FT.java:66)
```

I checked separately by creating a jdbc connection to the same machine and I was able to connect.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to master repository works ok and the problem is with connecting to work repository. Please check if

- Your WORKREP1 connection is correctly defined in master repository
- You can connect to the work repository manually

Also try connecting only to master repository to see if it works

```
final OdiInstance odiInstance = OdiInstance.createInstance(new OdiInstanceConfig(masterInfo, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should login to ODI with Master repostory login, go to the `Topology` tab.

There, under `Physical Architecture` go to `Agents` and open the agent. At `Definition`, agent host should not be localhost, but have a valid qualified hostname.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Our DB host changed where 11G ODI repository was residing, so we got a new TNS string, and we wanted to update the connection information for an existing ODI Master & Work Repository.

Action:

First, update odiparam.bat|sh and update hostname

Second, update ODI connection hostname at startup, but this time login as Master only.

Third, go to Topology → Repository → Work Repositories →  → double click to open → connection button (plug) → update relevant JDBC URL for your work repo and test.

Four, now log out, edit connection to now login as WORK REPO, and it should work